# friendly id path in checkbox_tag rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I'm currently getting this in my checkboxes data-url "/todos?id=f483e4a8cb1a728f" when it should just be "/todos/f483e4a8cb1a728f" I'm using friendly id for the random slugs.

Currently I'm calling it as data: { remote: true, url: url_for(controller: :todos, id: todo), method: "PATCH" } id: todo and I have tried todo.id but that gives me the number of the post which I don't want - I want the slug.

Does anyone know how I could get around this?

Thank you kind sirs.

EDIT: More Context as Requested

```
<%= check_box_tag 'todo[completed]', todo.id, todo.completed, data: { remote: true, url: url_for(controller: :todos, id: todo), method: "PATCH" }, id: todo.id %>
<%= label_tag todo.id, "COMPLETE", :class => 'strikethrough' %>
```

This is how I'm calling it - as I want to complete my todo on the index rather than going in and updating on todos/:id/edit. However, it gives me an error when I click the checkbox because the URL is like this "/todos?id=f483e4a8cb1a728f" when it should just be "/todos/f483e4a8cb1a728f"

EDIT:

My Action

```
def completed
    if @todo.update_attributes(:completed => params[:completed])
      flash[:success] = "Wowzers."
      redirect_to dashboard_path
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Not so wowzers..."  
      render :new  
    end
  end
```

My Routes

```
resources :todos do
    member do
      # post 'completed'
      patch 'todos/:id' => 'todos#completed'
    end 
  end
```

Comment: Calling what and how? Can you include a bit more context?

Comment: Updated, hope this provides more insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need a route configured as `patch '/todos/:id'`.

If you already have, put the name of the action in the `url_for` parameters, like:

`url_for(controller: :todos, action: :something, id: todo.id)`

If you haven't that action, you have to create it.

The `url_for` is returning `/todos?id=f483e4a8cb1a728f` because it is considering the `index` action as default, and as this path don't have an `:id` parameter inside the path, the helper put it as a parameter (query string).

Comment: I have an action set up already, but adding in patch '/todos/:id' has given me  an error 'Missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your routes.' I have never seen it before, could you please clarify?

Comment: How did you defined it? I think the simplest syntax is `patch 'todos/:id' => 'todos#your_action'`.

Comment: Ohh sorry, my bad. The only problem now is it displays the id twice '/todos/e3309e65a5f225ec696807ee1f5be3/todos/e3309e65a5f225ec696807ee1f5be3' or 'todos/19/todos/19' if I do id: todo.id as oppose to just todo

Comment: That's weird... isn't the route definition duplicated too? Like: `todos/:id/todos/:id`?

Comment: Yeah, the route and the ID seem to be duplicated :/ I can't see why it has, I'll just look over my checkbox_tag again and make sure I didn't delete anything or forget to do something after adding the action: :completed

Comment: upon doing a rake routes it's set to /todos/:id/todos/:id(.:format) but I'm really not sure why. Is this because of how I set up the route? Could you please take a look above at my edit?

Comment: Yes, that's because you put it inside a `member` block. If you want to keep it like that, just put `patch '/' => 'todos#completed'`, or move it outside that block.